# Trying to download a file from a link but failed (using python request)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I got a link that downloads a pdf file:

https://eclass.cccmyc.edu.hk/home/imail/downloadattachment.php?CampusMailID=441933&b_filename=TEkgSE8gWVVFTjREMTAucGRm

But instead of downloading the pdf, it redirects me to the login page of that platform. I am now trying to use python to login and download the file, here is my code:

```
import requests


url = "https://eclass.cccmyc.edu.hk/login.php"
download_url = "https://eclass.cccmyc.edu.hk/home/imail/downloadattachment.php?CampusMailID=441933&b_filename=TEkgSE8gWVVFTjREMTAucGRm"

data = {
    "UserLogin": "myUsername",
    "UserPassword": "secret"
}

r = requests.get(url, data=data)
```

I suppose I have logged in by now, so I download that file:

```
r = requests.get(download_url, allow_redirects=True)
open('my_pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Sadly, instead of downloading the pdf file, the program gives me some bunches of HTML codes. What should I do? I am pretty sure that I have made a big error in the program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet you can use and try.

```py
with requests.get(download_url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
            # If you have chunk encoded response uncomment if
            # and set chunk_size parameter to None.
            if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Sadly the code didn't work, my pc cannot open the pdf properly.